Slurm Accounting with slurmdbd
I set up a slurm test cluster and want to enable accounting. I can submit and run jobs. However sacct returns an empty table. The table cluster_job_table in the my slurm_acct_db database is empty as well.
I noticed when running a job, there is an error in the slurmctld.log. Does that mean slurmdbd can't connect?
sched: Allocate JobId=7 NodeList=slurm-worker #CPUs=1 Partition=debug
error: DBD_SEND_MULT_JOB_START message from invalid uid

There are no other errors in the logs.
I tried to configure slurm following the Slurm docs.
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/slurmdbd
AccountingStorageHost=localhost
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/linux

What should I do to make slurmdbd collect accounting information for the jobs?

The solution for me was to add to the slurmdbd.config:
AuthType=auth/munge
AuthInfo=/var/run/munge/munge.socket.2
LogFile=/var/log/slurm/slurmdbd.log
PidFile=/var/run/slurm/slurmdbd.pid
SlurmUser=slurm
StorageHost=localhost
StoragePort=3306

